# How to solve this issue "Standard outputs should not be used directly to log anything "

Tags: java, sonarqube

I need a print statement. But sonar not allowed this type.

```
String txt="Something";
System.out.println("Print: "+txt);
```

Expected output:

```
Print: Something
```

I tried this format logger.log().its not working for our requirement.

Comment: *"not working for our requirement"* can you tell more about what your requirements are?

Comment: @Joni Just print the statement in the console.

Comment: Ok, that should be doable with any logging framework. What logging framework do you use - what is `logger`?

Comment: i tired this `logger.log(Level.INFO, "Print: " + txt);` . But this error **"Preconditions" and logging arguments should not require evaluation (java:S2629)** is occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonarqube does not like it if you use `System.out`, or if you have string concatenation or other computation in the arguments you pass to the logging function. Construct the full message on a separate line before logging it:

```
String txt = "Print: " + "Something";

String logMessage = "Print: " + txt;
logger.log(Level.INFO, logMessage);
```

Comment: That just hides the computation of the argument from Sonar. If you willing to do that, you may as well use `@SupressWarning` or `//NOSONAR`

Answer (score 0):

If logger is not meeting your requirements, make it to do so by configuring it.

There are some widely used logging frameworks that are highly configurable and I doubt that they will not be able to do whatever you are doing with plain `System.out.println`

For example, check out very popular `SLF4J` and `Logback` as logging provider.

http://www.slf4j.org/

http://logback.qos.ch/

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a workaround, it hides the issue from sonar but does not solve it.

The point of the warning is to avoid code that needs to run even when the logging level is high enough that the message wont be printed. With this:

```
log.debug(string1 + string2);
```

You will compute a new String even if you completely discard the result.

I do not know what logging-framework you use, but I expect it to have a *format-string* and 0 or more objects in its signature, so you can write this:

```
log.debug("{} {}", string1, string2);
```

Now, if the configuration is such that debug-messages are not printed, no extra-string will be computed. The point is that the computation happens only *after* the decision of whether something should be printed is made.